# Why LinqDataSource RaiseViewChanged() not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have some code like this :

```
   private IQueryable Search()
   {
     //dcBase is my DataContext instance
     var q = from p in dcBase.Users
            select new
            {
                p.ID,
                p.FirstName,
                p.LastName
            };
     return q;

    }
    protected void ldsResult_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = Search();
}
protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckValidate())
    {
        Save();
        ldsResult.RaiseViewChanged(); 
        ClearForm();
    }
}
```

for the first time , when page is load `Search()` method fires after `ldsResult_Selecting` , but when I change something and call `dcBase.SubmitChange()` in the `Save()` method ,It dosen't fires at all even I call `ldsResult.RaiseViewChanged();` after `Save()` method ?? and this happens 2 times until now in past 2 years, what can be the cause ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sth , It happens when there is no data to bind in the first time !!! and if I replace 'ldsResult.RaiseViewChanged();' in the 'btnsend_Click' with 'dlResult.DataBind();' it works correctly